# Enum as instance variables

Tags: java, enums, scjp

If you have an enum such as

```
enum Coffee {
    BIG,
    SMALL
}
```

and a class that has an instance variable like this of the enum:

```
public class MyClass {
    private Coffee coffee;

    // Constructor etc.
}
```

Why is it possible in the constructor to say e.g. `coffee.BIG`?
I don't understand that you can use the reference? Is enum as instance variables initialized to something other than `null`? It is the self test question #4 in the SCJP book in the first chapter. *I tried to shorten the code and question.*

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In

```
enum Coffee {
    BIG,
    SMALL
}
```

BIG or SMALL are `public static final` fields of Coffee class, and like all static fields they can be accessed by class name like

```
Coffee b1 = Coffee.BIG;
```

or by reference of same type as class, like

```
Coffee s2 = b1.SMALL;
Coffee s3 = Coffee.BIG.SMALL; //BIG is reference of type Coffee so it is OK (but looks strange)
```

But lets remember that **we should avoid accessing static members via references**. This creates confusion since we are not really accessing members of *instance* but members of *class* (so for instance there is no polymorphic behaviour).

Answer (score 14):

This is what happens **behind the scenes** :

```
E:\workspace>type Coffee.java
public enum Coffee {
    BIG,
    SMALL
}

E:\workspace>javap Coffee
Compiled from "Coffee.java"
public final class Coffee extends java.lang.Enum<Coffee> {
  public static final Coffee BIG;
  public static final Coffee SMALL;
  public static Coffee[] values();
  public static Coffee valueOf(java.lang.String);
  static {};
}
```

As you can see `BIG` and `SMALL` are essentially static fields in your enum.

The [**JLS**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9.2) also make this part clear :

> In addition to the members that an enum type E inherits from Enum,
>   for each declared enum constant with the name n, the enum type has an
>   implicitly declared public static final field named n of type E. These
>   fields are considered to be declared in the same order as the
>   corresponding enum constants, before any static fields explicitly
>   declared in the enum type. Each such field is initialized to the enum
>   constant that corresponds to it.

Hope this clarifies your question.

Answer (score 6):

Before Java 5 the way to implement enums was to create a class with private constructor and public final fields of the same class initialised to specific values.

Since Java 5, enum construct is effectively a sugar that does the same, and takes care of things like null values are not allowed, enum values become public static fields etc.